# How many organisations are involved in missions that go further than the moon?

Tags: future-missions

I'm trying to get an idea of how many missions are planning to go further than the moon?

I'd like to know which companies or organisations are doing, or planning to do this (e.g. missions to Mars or further). Of course NASA are doing these things and SpaceX are planning for Mars. I'm new to the field so any information would be great.

I'd also like to know roughly how many of these kinds of mission happen each year, and if that will increase in the future.

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the site! You could answer this question with some basic research on the web, Wikipedia has a page on future space missions, as so several other sites like NASA, EASA, etc. Your question is also very broad, asking for a list, which is off topic. I suggest you do some basic research and then come back with some specific questions after checking if they've already been answered.

Comment: Other than NASA and SpaceX, I can think of the Objective Europa organization which aims to send people to Jupiter's moon Europa one way. And Russia thinks about a manned mission to Ganymede, another moon of Jupiter.